# Some Software Manager for Mac OS X like Synaptic in Ubuntu

Tags: software, firefox, web-browser, package-management, opera

Is there some software manager like Synpatic in Ubunut for Mac OS X....
Right now, I am using kind of old Mac OS X 10.5.8 and want to install softare on it...
Like Opera, Firefox... 
I don't mind that the versions of browsers I can install on this Mac OS X system are not secure anymore... I will not use it that much... I can still use Safari...
The problem is I don't know which versions of Opera and Firefox I can install...
For example, I installed the newest Opera and now it says :

> You cannot use this version of Opera with this version of Mac OS X.

Answer (score 1):

There are two main systems for unix software on OS X: [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/) and [Fink](http://www.finkproject.org/)

Fink is akin to (and iirc based on) the Debian/Ubunutu `apt` system: it delivers pre-compiled binaries. MacPorts is related to the older BSD Ports collections: rather than pre-built binaries, it containers pointers to the original source + patches required to make that source work on your platform (and with the other apps that you've installed via ports).

There's also a newer tool called [Homebrew](http://github.com/mxcl/homebrew) which I've not used; but it claims to provide better interoperability with things you've installed by hand, and rely more on the native Mac libraries instead of just the installed libraries.

A [quick search](https://superuser.com/search?q=osx+package-management+fink+macports) shows a variety of questions already talking about Macports and Fink and differences between them.

Source: https://superuser.com/a/92885/256923